# iOS 16 Beta Vertically Aligns Navigation Bar Title View Differently with Right Bar Items

Tags: uikit, uinavigationbar

On iOS 16, I noticed that the navigation bar title view is being aligned vertically to the top, I cannot figure out why. The odd thing is that some view controllers are fine (it's centered vertically). But some it's top aligned.

I thought maybe it had something to do with right/left bar button items, but after playing around with it - it doesn't seem to matter.

Is there some change in UIKit that is causing this?

Centered (In view controller A):

[image: Centered]

Top Aligned (In view controller B):

[image: Top Aligned]

My component is the same in all cases where this heart graphic is - it's a subclass of UIImageView that sets the image to the heart.

Additionally. The affected view controllers are the root view controller for navigation controller, that are in a tab bar controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from Apple:

> This is a bug where if you switch between the built in and custom
> title views we don't always update the layout correctly. I don't
> recall if there is a workaround, but this is fixed in a future build.

It isn't fixed as of iOS 16 beta 7. Let's hope the GM is fixed.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this information from Apple ?

Comment: Here's the reference: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/713676. Here one of the comment is from an Apple Engineer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use autolayout, it seems that on iOS 16.0 `updateConstraints` method isn't called in some cases. If you set up constraints by overriding this method (as I did), you can try to move this logic in `init`.